# Windows application to view online broadcast games

Tags: online

Are there some windows applications that can view online games? Ideally they should allow custom moves and analysis. Something similar to Chess24 or FollowChess app on android? Only no web browser solutions please. Preferably free license.

Comment: Why do you need a no web browser solution?

Comment: @ericw31415 Friend preparing online with live commentary dislike web solution because it might be problematic for commentators to deal with possible errors during live show and that it might be tricky to prepare the scene. The program to create the scene is capturing rectangles on selected windows and he is worried about it being web browser windows, with scrollbars, changing content... This is problem, how big it is, that's another question.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that what you want is to take a live pgn from the web and have the game displayed live in a window on your computer?

Comment: @user1583209 I am looking for stable layout solution for capturing video to create live show from some tournament. I'm not sure web based solutions are best for doing that, even though playchess may be quite acceptable. The capturing program recognizes windows, their location, title, rectangle you are interested in... Programs are usually more friendly for this task than content changing scrollable web pages. I used this capturing program to create video lessons, nice and clean, no disturbing setup position windows, database window, search dialogs... Just board over almost all the screen.

Comment: @user1583209 The point is to have possibility to feed professional capturing program capable of more than only capturing rectangle of some part of a screen. It has window filters, it can show content of window even if there is another window over it, create desired video layout no matter how you move these windows. Nice looking show from tournament is what we try to create :-)

Comment: Open Broadcaster Software has an option to capture a portion of the screen, so you could use an in-browser solution.